# Mockito error when using 'when' function

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm getting the below error when trying to use mockito

```
"the method when(t) in the type mockito is not applicable for the arguments (void)"
```

My code looks something like,

```
when(myFun(arg1, arg2)).thenReturn(fun());
```

myfun is not `void`. I found some posts in SO where the same error occurs because of `myFun` returning `void`, but that's not true in my case. Is there any other reason why this might occur?

Comment: Where's the object that `myFun` belongs to? It should be `when(someMock.myFun(arg1, arg2)))`, surely?

Comment: Can you post a sample code of the failing myFun?